# Animation Nodes: How to create splines between a particle system and an object based on distance?

Tags: particles, animation-nodes, splines

I would first like to mention that I am a beginner to Blender and Animation Nodes. I am trying to create an animation where an icosphere orbits above a plane that emits particles, and if the particles are close enough to the sphere as it passes, will create a spline between the icosphere and the particle. So far in my animation nodes, I am able to find the distances between the icosphere and the particles, but I am unsure how to implement a sort of if statement (like the find close points node) to select only the particles that are a certain distance away, and then use the create spline to create a spline between the icosphere and these particles. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It is very easy to do with *Animation Nodes* by using the *KDTree node*.

**Method:**

1. First construct the KDTree from the position of the particles. Then, use the *[Find Points in a Radius](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/tree/find_points_in_radius/)* node to find the points/particles (shown by red color) within a radius from the *Vector* which is the position of the object (in this case is a Sphere).
   [image]
2. Now, to make splines from the Sphere for each red-points/particles, we have to use the *Loop* node, with which we create a vector list from the sphere's position and each red-points position. Then use the *Spline From Points* node to create the splines from the previously created vector list, and the *Curve Object Output* node generates the *Curve Object*.
   [image]

**Blend File:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, this is exactly what I wanted, I only have one question. I am trying to replicate what you did, and I can not seem to find the splines list node you have at the end of the subprogram that inputs a spline and outputs a spline list. I thought it might be a create spline list, but I can't get it to look like yours. Thanks again!

Comment: I did not use any Splines List node. There are two nodes for the spline list, one is Create Spline List node and the other is the Combine Spline Lists node.